# How to append a Value in cck field in a for loop?

Tags: 6, nodes, entities

I want to keep a progress field in my content type so i can update value in it. But it doesn't take the previous value if saved in for loop.

```
for($i = 1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    $mynode = node_load(6);
    $myprevious = $mynode->field_progress[0]['value'];
    drupal_set_message("My Previous".$myprevious);
    $mynode->field_progress[0]['value'] = $myprevious." ".$i." ";
    node_submit($mynode);
    node_save($mynode);
}
$mynode = node_load(6);
drupal_set_message("My Value".$mynode->field_progress[0]['value']);
$myprevous_progress = $mynode->field_progress[0]['value'];
$mynode->field_progress[0]['value'] = $myprevous_progress.' end.'.$myprevous_progress;
node_save($mynode);
```

Output on page :

```
My Previous
My Previous
My Previous
My Previous
My Previous
My Value
```

Comment: are you on 6 or 7?

Comment: @MohammedShameem 6. but i solved it check my answer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved It by using

```
$mynode = node_load(6); //Load the node before for loop
for($i = 1; $i<=5; $i++) {
    $myprevious = $mynode->field_progress[0]['value'];
    drupal_set_message("My Previous".$myprevious);
    $mynode->field_progress[0]['value'] = $myprevious." ".$i." ";
    node_submit($mynode);
    node_save($mynode);
}
drupal_set_message("My Value".$mynode->field_progress[0]['value']);
$myprevous_progress = $mynode->field_progress[0]['value'];
$mynode->field_progress[0]['value'] = $myprevous_progress.' end.'.$myprevous_progress;
node_save($mynode);
```

Comment: I really can't see what/why you are doing/trying to accomplish here, but, if a node is already in the drupal database, eg, you can `node_load()` it, I can't see a reason to `node_submit()` it before `node_save()`ing it again.

Comment: I just want to append a value with existing value. Like in loop. But if i place node_load inside for loop then it doesn't work. I placed it outside of for loop then it works.